# Trying to identify 1970s kids show with solid blue eyed humanoid called Sky (?)

Tags: story-identification, aliens

In the early '70s I saw a kid's show where the title sequence showed a presumably crash-landed humanoid unconscious in a forest, slowly covered with falling leaves. In the first episode he is found by a boy or teenager, who I think calls him "Sky", because the alien's eyes are solid, startling blue - no pupil, iris or white. I suspect it was on BBC1.
Can anyone help me with any details about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh, oops. Just found it through Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_(TV_serial)

Comment: Self-answers are cool, it shows you don't stop and rely on others' work.  You can check your own check-mark.

Comment: Thank you Solemnity, I had felt a bit silly about this.